# Is there any way to determine the signal that was caught from inside a bash trap function?

Tags: bash, signals

I have a `bash` script, in which I have specified via `trap` that a function will be called for any (catchable) `signal`.

```
typeset -i sig=1
while (( sig < 65 )); do
    trap myfunc $sig
    let sig=sig+1
done
```

Is there any way my script can determine which `signal` has been caught?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
trap "signum=${sig};myfunc" "$sig"
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for thinking outside the box.

Comment: I think it may be better this way `trap "myfunc $sig" $sig` or with a switch, instead of embedding name to get at $1.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're trying to pass the value of the signal you've caught to the action you want to take.  Try something like this:

```
# 1     SIGHUP
# 2     SIGINT
# 3     SIGQUIT
# 6     SIGABRT
# 9     SIGKILL
# 14    SIGALRM
# 15    SIGTERM

for sig in 1 2 3 6 9 14 15; do
    trap 'echo "caught signal '$sig'..."' $sig
done
```

Comment: You cannot trap signal 9 (`SIGKILL`).